# How can I backup and/or restore MMS messages on another phone?

Tags: mms, google-backup

**Context**

I recently got a new Android phone. (OnePlus Nord N200 5G for reference.) On my old phone (LG V30+) I utilized the "Backup" in the Settings. On my new phone, I was asked if I wanted to restore from a backup, so I did. Everything seemed fine.

Later, I realized that MMS messages did not back up. It's as if they were never sent, and old Text conversations don't make sense with those pieces missing.

**Goal**

My ideal situation is: I can restore those messages and they will slot right into where they belong in conversation order. I would also accept just being able to easily save all MMS messages across all contacts somewhere, if my real goal is not possible.

**What I've tried**

It seems to be the case that the old "backup" stuff in the settings has been replaced by Google One. Indeed, in Google One, there is a checkbox for "backup MMS messages" that is separate from "backup SMS messages." However, it doesn't seem to be possible to restore those backed up MMS messages without resetting the new phone back to factory settings. But I have a month of new conversations that I don't want to delete, either! So I don't think there's a way with that app.

I have seen dozens of sketchy looking apps promising to be able to do something with my MMS messages. However, I don't trust any of them, and through searching haven't been able to find anything that I feel confidently says it can do what I want.

I'm vaguely aware that these messages are stored in a SQLite database on the phone. I have not attempted to copy this database or otherwise merge the data in them, though am willing to give it a shot if this is necessary. I know my way around databases, but have low confidence the simple solutions will work here. (Expecting security things, or checksums, or anything.)

Neither of my phones are rooted, and I would personally like to keep it that way, but if necessary I'm willing to go through those steps. But even with that, I haven't seen anything that suggests that creates an easily solution either.

What can I do?

Comment: While indeed most such apps look sketchy (just count the trackers inside!), I'd say you can trust apps from F-Droid (disclosure: I'm one of the F-Droid maintainers). [SMS Import/Export](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.tmo1.sms_ie/) could do the trick: it exports to JSON (so you can easily use that with other apps) and also allows to import from that. I haven't tried it (didn't receive a single MMS yet in all those years), hence just a comment. If it works for you, feel free to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) :)